# ASP.NET: Web Deployment Task Failed - microsoft.web.publishing.targets

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, build, msbuild, web-config

I am in the process of moving away from FTP and into webDeploy. I first built a sample web application with just a webpage, and that deployed fine. I then added a connectionString and a page that accesses data, and that deployed fine.

Then I added forms authentication with a custom data store and that did not deploy fine. I then used FTP to move all of my files, and they successfully transferred and the website functions as it should. So webDeploy must not like something that was added to the web.config when I added forms authentication, but I don't know what that something is.

This is an ASP.NET Web Form application on .NET 4.5.

**What was added to the web.config, after webDeploy started giving me the error**

```
<membership defaultProvider="MyMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="MyMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" 
    connectionStringName="MyCs" 
    enablePasswordRetrieval="false" 
    enablePasswordReset="true" 
    requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" 
    requiresUniqueEmail="false" 
    maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" 
    minRequiredPasswordLength="6" 
    passwordAttemptWindow="10" 
    applicationName="/"/>
  </providers>
</membership>

<profile defaultProvider="MyProfileProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="MyProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider" connectionStringName="MyCs" applicationName="/"/>
  </providers>
</profile>

<roleManager defaultProvider="MyRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="MyRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider" connectionStringName="MyCs" applicationName="/"/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>

<sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="MySessionProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="MySessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider" connectionStringName="MyCs"/>
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

**The last part of the build output:**

```
Generate source manifest file for Web Deploy package/publish ...
Start Web Deploy Publish the Application/package to https://myServer/msdeploy.axd?site=mySite.com ...

Starting Web deployment task from source: manifest(C:\Users\ME\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Samples
\MyApp\MyApp\obj\Debug\Package\MyApp.SourceManifest.xml) to Destination: auto().

Adding ACL's for path (mySite)
C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(4196,5):
 Error : Web deployment task failed. ((9/26/2013 11:36:26 PM) An error occurred when the request 
was processed on the remote computer.)

(9/26/2013 11:36:26 PM) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.
The server experienced an issue processing the request. Contact the server administrator for 
more information.
Publish failed to deploy.
```

**Okay so lets look at line 4196 and column 5 of microsot.web.publishing.targets**

```
4196      <VSMSDeploy
4167      Condition="!$(UseMsdeployExe)"
4198      MSDeployVersionsToTry="$(_MSDeployVersionsToTry)"
4199      Source="@(MsDeploySourceProviderSetting)"
4200      Destination="@(MsDeployDestinationProviderSetting)"
          DisableLink="$(PublishDisableLinks)"
          EnableLink="$(PublishEnableLinks)"
          AllowUntrustedCertificate="$(AllowUntrustedCertificate)"
          BuildingInsideVisualStudio="$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)"
          SkipExtraFilesOnServer="$(SkipExtraFilesOnServer)"
          .....

>
```

Now I am at a dead end because I do not know what I am looking at. Any ideas? I am not sure what code is relevant, so please let me know if something else would be of assistance.

Comment: I'm on Visual Studio 2013, same thing.